# Is there a way to take highest confidence result only in VisionLabelDetector?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-mlkit

To archive this, I was thinking about take 1 result only which is the top one so I check the documentation and [VisionCloudDetectorOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemlvision/api/reference/Classes/VisionCloudDetectorOptions) have this variable `maxResults` so if I set it to 1, my goal is complete but this only work with Cloud-based image labeling. So I check [VisionLabelDetectorOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasemlvision/api/reference/Classes/VisionLabelDetectorOptions) which run locally and there is no option for that. And the result when printing out from this

```
return "Label: \(String(describing: feature.label)), " +
      "Confidence: \(feature.confidence), " +
      "EntityID: \(String(describing: feature.entityID)), " +
      "Frame: \(feature.frame)"
    }.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Will turn into this

```
Label: Food, Confidence: 0.795696, EntityID: /m/02wbm, Frame: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Label: Fruit, Confidence: 0.71232, EntityID: /m/02xwb, Frame: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Label: Vegetable, Confidence: 0.595484, EntityID: /m/0f4s2w, Frame: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Label: Plant, Confidence: 0.536178, EntityID: /m/05s2s, Frame: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

These are sample code I run from [Firebase/quickstart-ios](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/8445278e4e5040c2c2f91c9cd572b94c9a70bd8b/mlvision/MLVisionExample/ViewController.swift) starting at line 645.

My second solution is to do the `topResult` like in CoreML which is using `VNClassificationObservation` to return the first result. Something like this

```
guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation],
            let topResult = results.first else {
                fatalError("Unexpected result")
        }
```

but I haven't figured out how to replicate like that yet.

So, is there a way to take the highest `Confidence` label only? In this case is the `Food` label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `labels` is the array containing all the VisionLabel objects returned by `VisionLabelDetector.detect(in:completion:)`, usually all the labels in the array are already sorted based on their `confidence` from highest to lowest, so you can simply get the highest `confidence` label with `labels.first`.

If you want to be extra safe and pick the highest confidence label yourself, you could do the following:

`let topLabel = labels.max(by: { (a, b) -> Bool in
   return a.confidence < b.confidence
 })`

Comment: And in this case, the example repo, they used `features`. Just add `features.top` then print out the result like above and we will have the highest confidence label. Thanks for the suggestion!